# How to Create , Edit and store data in root bundle files in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need is to "edit" a json file that is on my assets folder. To read a file from assets I can use this:

`Future<String> setFileData(String path) async { return await rootBundle.loadString(path); }`

But No Found any Method to write data in the same file
The problem is that i need to call data from api request and store it to working directory like as assets or lib folder in flutter project.
All The Answer and methods that i found it store data on the mobile device and i don't need that

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmpvG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `assets` directory is read-only. You need to write your files somewhere on the device, see for example: [Read and write files](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files)

Comment: okay , is there any way to write data in files under lib directory?

Comment: @AsmaaKhaled No, the lib directory is for source files, it doesn't exist in the running app.